# ¿Cómo individualizar widgets de tkinter (Python)?

Tags: python, tkinter

Me gustaría crear un programa usando tkinter y openpyxl para mostrar rápidamente las calificaciones de mis alumnos.

Dada una hoja de cálculo como la siguiente (simplificación):
[image: Hoja de cálculo simplificada]

¿Cómo puedo crear tantos checkbuttons como estudiantes/nombres haya en un aula de tal manera que posteriormente ***al clicar*** en una de esas casillas pueda mostrar las calificaciones de dicho alumno?

Con mi código, al ir clicando no consigo nada.
[image: Tkinter GUI]

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from tkinter import *
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('marks.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active

names_and_rows = {}

for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    names_and_rows[name] = i

root = Tk()
root.title("Student's marks")

students_names = Frame(root, bd=1, relief="solid")
students_names.pack(side="left")

student_marks = Frame(root, bd=1, relief="solid")
student_marks.pack(side="right")

message = Label(student_marks, text="You still haven't checked on a 
    ny student's name")
message.pack()


def get_marks(v):
    marks = ""
    for i in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):
        information = str(sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value) + ": " 
            + str(sheet.cell(row=v, column=i).value) + "\n"
        marks = marks + information
    if (v.get() == 1):
        message.config(text=marks)
    else:
        message.config(text="You still haven't checked on any 
            student's name")


list_of_widgets = []

for k, v in names_and_rows.items():
    square = Checkbutton(students_names, variable=v, onvalue=1, 
        offvalue=0, text=k, command=lambda: get_marks(v))
    list_of_widgets.append(square)
    square.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[Simplified Worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lWrw.png)

[Tkinter GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDH9e.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mariano, tengo dos posibles soluciones.

1.- Por un lado, revisé tú código, y agregué el nombre del *widget* a los datos sobre los que iteras para crear los checkbutton de forma dinámica. Esto es un poco sucio, pero funciona:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import openpyxl

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('origen.xlsx', data_only=True)
sheet = wb.active

datosXls = {}
contador = 1
for i in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    name = sheet.cell(row=i, column=1).value
    datosXls[name] = {"ex1": None, "ex2": None, "ex3": None,
                      "fila": i,
                      "widget":("!checkbutton" + ("" if contador < 2 else str(contador)))}
    contador += 1

root = Tk()
root.title("Student's marks")

students_names = Frame(root, bd=1, relief="solid")
students_names.pack(side="left")

student_marks = Frame(root, bd=1, relief="solid")
student_marks.pack(side="right")

message = Label(student_marks, text="You still haven't checked on any student's name")
message.pack()

def get_marks(widget, fila):
    marks = ""
    for i in range(2, sheet.max_column + 1):
        information = str(sheet.cell(row=1, column=i).value) + ": " + str(sheet.cell(row=fila, column=i).value) + "\n"
        marks += information

    if ("selected" in students_names.children[widget].state()):
        message.config(text=marks)
    else:
        message.config(text="You still haven't checked on any student's name")

for nombre in datosXls.keys():
    square = ttk.Checkbutton(students_names, text=nombre,
                             command=lambda nombre_widget=datosXls[nombre]["widget"],
                             fila_xsl=datosXls[nombre]["fila"] : get_marks(nombre_widget, fila_xsl))
    square.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Originalmente, en tu código, usabas un checkbutton de tkinter. Lo cambié por uno tkinter.ttk, que es algo más potente y que además me salva de tener que usar el atributo variable, que era lo que te daba problemas y no te permitía "individualizar" cada control. Al tener el nombre del widget, y pasárselo a la función que obtiene los datos, ésta puede buscar dentro de los controles asociados al Frame students_names, y evaluar el estado del checkbutton consultado.

> students_names.children[widget].state()

El resto es bastante similar a como lo tenías

2.- Por otra parte, creo que el tipo de problema se resuelve mejor con otro tipo de widget, un combobox:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Label
from tkinter import ttk
from openpyxl import load_workbook

libro = load_workbook('origen.xlsx', data_only=True)
hoja = libro.active

datosXls = {}

for fila in range(2, hoja.max_row+1):
  datosXls[hoja.cell(row=fila, column=1).value] = {"Ex1": hoja.cell(row=fila, column=2).value,
                                                   "Ex2": hoja.cell(row=fila, column=3).value,
                                                   "Ex3": hoja.cell(row=fila, column=4).value
                                                   }



ventana = Tk()
ventana.title("Notas de alumnos")

def traerAlumno(evt):
  ex1.config(text=datosXls[lista_alumnos.get()]["Ex1"])
  ex2.config(text=datosXls[lista_alumnos.get()]["Ex2"])
  ex3.config(text=datosXls[lista_alumnos.get()]["Ex3"])


Label(ventana, text="Alumnos").grid(row=0, column=0)
lista_alumnos = ttk.Combobox(ventana, values=list(datosXls.keys()))
lista_alumnos.grid(row=0, column=1)
lista_alumnos.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", traerAlumno)
Label(ventana, text="Ex1").grid(row=1, column=0)
Label(ventana, text="Ex2").grid(row=1, column=1)
Label(ventana, text="Ex3").grid(row=1, column=2)

ex1 = Label(ventana, text="")
ex2 = Label(ventana, text="")
ex3 = Label(ventana, text="")
ex1.grid(row=2, column=0)
ex2.grid(row=2, column=1)
ex3.grid(row=2, column=2)

ventana.mainloop()
```

Inicialmente, obtengo los datos desde el mismo archivo, y los agrego al diccionario **datosXls**, luego dibujo la interfaz. No necesito ninguna creación dinámica, porque todos los datos están contenidos en un solo control. El combobox, tiene enlazado un evento de selección, el cual llama a la función **traerAlumno**, que obtiene cada una de las notas y las asigna a las etiquetas designadas.